# Custom UIView touch area

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, touchesbegan

Hello I have some weird shapes that I need to handle the `touchesBegan` method on. The issue is that `UIViews` are square and the only way I could do it is to maybe declare a grid and then check the coordinates. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: The touches* methods give you a set of UITouch objects, and the coords of these touches can be found using a method (locationInView: IIRC).

Comment: yeah but if i have weird uiview shapes, there would be transparent areas. Thinking about detecting if the touched area is transparent.

Comment: that would essentially mean i would need to declare the area for each . A bit cumbersome and too much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `hitTest:withEvent:` in your UIView subclass. Return YES only if the CGPoint is inside the shape.

Check out this question for polygon shapes:
[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have access this talk at WWDC 2012 was pretty awesome with respect to how to handle complex touch events:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=200